# Two dimensional array in Javascript, [num][value1, value2, value3]

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a 2D array in JS that I can return from my method.  I basically want to do something like this:

```
var msg[][4] = [][entryID, entryName, entryURL, entryDesc];
for (var i = 0, len = bookmarks.length; i < len; i++) {
   var id = bookmarks[i].getElementsByTagName('id')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
   var name = bookmarks[i].getElementsByTagName('name')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
   var url = bookmarks[i].getElementsByTagName('url')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
   var desc = bookmarks[i].getElementsByTagName('desc')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
    msg[i][entryID] = id;
    msg[i][entryName] = name;
    msg[i][entryURL] = entryURL;
    msg[i][entryDesc] = entryDesc;
}
```

The first line msg[][4] throws an error.  I'm not sure if or how I can do something like that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `entryID` etc is supposed to be a string, then I think what you actually want is an array of objects:

```
var msg = [];
for (var i = 0, len = bookmarks.length; i < len; i++) {
    msg.push({
        entryID: bookmarks[i].getElementsByTagName('id')[0].firstChild.nodeValue,
        entryName: bookmarks[i].getElementsByTagName('name')[0].firstChild.nodeValue,
        entryURL: bookmarks[i].getElementsByTagName('url')[0].firstChild.nodeValue,
        entryDesc: bookmarks[i].getElementsByTagName('desc')[0].firstChild.nodeValue,
    });
}
```

You can then access e.g. the second entry with `msg[1].entryID`. Instead of creating an object, you can simply create an array as well, but using an object is more descriptive in my opinion.

---

JavaScript does not have multi-dimensional arrays. What you can create are arrays of arrays (of arrays...) or arrays of objects (of arrays/objects ...). Arrays in JavaScript are dynamic, therefore it is not necessary to initialize them with any size. Just keep adding whatever vaue you want to the array.